# why am i getting an error even if i have the latest verison of react and there is no logical error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i was learning react and this was the first file that i had started with
in that i tried entering another div and tried with <>

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <h1>this is me</h1>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

this was the code that i had
but the moment i used<> it became an error

```
rror in ./src/App.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (7:7)

   5 |   render() {
   6 |     return (
>  7 |       <>
     |        ^
   8 |       <h1>this is me</h1>
   9 |       <div className="App">
  10 |         <div className="E
```

what should i do to get rid of this?